# Character wrongly encoded

Tags: php, character-encoding, filesystems

I've got files containing the character `⌐` in their name.

These files are well handled under Linux (Apache/php):

```php
$files = scandir($path);
echo json_encode($files);
```

> file1⌐
>   file2⌐
>   file3⌐
>   file4⌐

Under Windows they seem to be read as *Windows-1252* by the file system, so I had to conditionally convert them so that `json_encode` could work

```php
$files = scandir($path);
foreach ($files as $i => $file) {
    $files[$i] = mb_convert_encoding($file, 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1252');
}
echo json_encode($files);
```

Here is how they get converted

> file1¬
>   file2¬
>   file3¬
>   file4¬

Why `⌐` is getting converted to `¬` and how can I get the original character ?

Comment: Little unclear what you want, but what I do know is that Linux uses a backslash and windows uses a forward one by default (but also supports backslashes). Try using that.

Comment: Weird thing is that Windows-1252 doesn't even have a character encoding for the "reverse not sign", but it does have one for the "not sign". Maybe you're not getting the string back in Windows-1252 like you thought? Have you tried doing a mb_detect_encoding() just to be sure?

Comment: I'm using `mb_check_encoding` which validates me _Windows-1252_. I also tried `mb_detect_encoding` (telling me it's not _UTF-8_). Good point for the "reverse not sign" absent of _Windows-1252_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try unpack('C*', $char) on the critical character ⌐ of your filenames. Then you will notice that it is already 0xAC (which is ¬).

The reason for this is, that scandir() uses an 8-bit ANSI Api of Windows that does a substitution and provides some "closest matching character" for characters that are not on Windows-1252. You can observe the same behaviour if you get the text-editor notepad++, set it to ANSI and try to copy&paste your ⌐ into it. It will show up as ¬ (and funnily it also changed in the c&p buffer when I tried it on my system).

What can you do? Well here are some options:

1. Use shell_exec('dir /b') on Windows (I tested this, you get the original character)
2. Assume that ¬ means ⌐ for filenames on Windows and just replace it back after utf-8 conversion
3. Change your software system so the character ⌐ is no longer used in filenames
4. Use some experimental php build that has the function [stream_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-encoding.php) and try the code below. (NB: stream_encoding is undefined, even with mbstring loaded, in the following official builds: 5.6.19 7.0.4)

```php
$myContext = stream_context_create();
stream_encoding($myContext, 'UTF-8');
$files = scandir('./', SCANDIR_SORT_ASCENDING, $myContext);
```

While shell_exec should be generally avoided, I think this is your best option for now. On the long term you should go for 3 if you can. I would not recommend 4. (also I have not tested this) and I do not know enough about your scenario to tell if 2. is viable.

Comment: [19-May-2018 23:10:05 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function stream_encoding()  in any PHP version from 4.4 to 7.2.5